# When using zsh, preexec: parse error in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

when I use zsh, exec this command as follow

`` $ echo "\`"
preexec: parse error
` ``

if change back bash, it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

preexec is a hook that runs before the command: "pre-exec"ution. My hunch is you've got some prompt or zsh framework like oh-my-zsh that is choking on "`" character.

> preexec
>
> Executed just after a command has been read and is about to be
>   executed. If the history mechanism is active (and the line was not
>   discarded from the history buffer), the string that the user typed is
>   passed as the first argument, otherwise it is an empty string. The
>   actual command that will be executed (including expanded aliases) is
>   passed in two different forms: the second argument is a single-line,
>   size-limited version of the command (with things like function bodies
>   elided); the third argument contains the full text that is being
>   executed.